# Migrate multiple source data rows

Tags: commerce, migrations

Has anyone tried migrating fields with multiple source data rows? In my case, Im migrating values of commerce file field (https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_file). It only migrated 1 id where it should have multiple id's. I've checked the query in the source database, it outputs correctly, my problem is upon migration.

Here's what I did.

```
$query->addExpression('GROUP_CONCAT(file.field_file_fid)', 'file_id');

/* … */

$this->addFieldMapping('commerce_file', 'file_id')
        ->sourceMigration('PrivateFile')
        ->separator(',');
$this->addFieldMapping('commerce_file:file_class')
        ->defaultValue('MigrateFileFid');
$this->addFieldMapping('commerce_file:preserve_files')
        ->defaultValue(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out that sourceMigration() doesn't allow multiple data source data rows (but please correct me if I'm wrong). So, I made a custom query in my prepareRow() that somehow works like sourceMigration. Here's what I did:

```
// group concat code
$query->addExpression('GROUP_CONCAT(file.field_file_fid)', 'file_id');

// in field mapping
$this->addFieldMapping('commerce_file', 'file_id');
$this->addFieldMapping('commerce_file:file_class')
      ->defaultValue('MigrateFileFid');

// in prepareRow()
public function prepareRow($row) {
  if (parent::prepareRow($row) === FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  // get the values of the file_id where you used group concat function
  $product_id1 = explode(",", $row->file_id); //convert csv to array
  $product_id1 = array_values($product_id1); //redeclare it to clear its index / optional
  $newsIds = array(); //array where the ids will be stored

  foreach ($product_id1 as $i) { //loop through array
      $getEquivalentId = db_select('migrate_map_privatefile', 'p') //'migrate_map_privatefile' is the migrate map table where the ids of the files are stored
              ->fields('p', array('destid1')) 
              ->condition('p.sourceid1', $i);
      $resultOfId = $getEquivalentId->execute();
      foreach ($resultOfId as $id) {
        $newsIds[] = $id->destid1; //store result to $newsIds
      }

    }

    $row->file_id = $newsIds; //the values of file_id will now be $newsIds

  }
```

Hope this would help someone, someday.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To migrate multiple values in destination database, we just need to provide source values in array.
[Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) module will automatically parse this array and migrate accordingly.

See this : https://www.drupal.org/node/1159234

**As per your code:**
You can prepare file id array in *prepareRow()* method of migrate module.

```
$row->file_id_array = array(fid1, fid2);
```

And in *__construct()* you can do field mapping like below:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('file_field', 'file_id_array');
    $this->addFieldMapping('file_field:file_class')
      ->defaultValue('MigrateFileUri');
    $this->addFieldMapping('file_field:destination_file', 'DESTINATION_FILENAMEs');
    $this->addFieldMapping('file_field:source_dir')
      ->defaultValue($file_path);
    $this->addFieldMapping('file_field:destination_dir')
      ->defaultValue(variable_get('file_default_scheme', 'public') . '://event');
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @mohit_rocks. However, I'm using source migration. And I just found out that source migration doesn't support multiple source data rows? Was that right?

Comment: So, I think my problem now would be how to create and prepare a query that works like sourceMigration() - (gets the migrated ids of the files).